# Vector question, differentials, Electromagnetism

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, vectors, differentiation

I was reading this demonstration of electric potential in my book:

> > Let $q$ be a point charge at point $P$
> >
> > The Electric field created at point $M$ by $q$ is :
> >
> > $$\vec{E}(M) = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{||\vec{PM}||^3}\vec{PM}$$
> >
> > The circulation of the field is :
> >
> > $$dC = \vec{E}(M)\cdot d\vec{OM} =  \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{||\vec{PM}||^3}\vec{PM}\cdot
> >  d\vec{OM}$$
> >
> > $P$ being a fixed point, $d\vec{OP} = \vec{0}$ and $d\vec{OM} = d\vec{OP}+d\vec{PM} = d\vec{PM}$.
> >
> > Since $\vec{PM}\cdot d\vec{PM} = \frac{1}{2}d(\vec{PM}\cdot \vec{PM}) = \frac{1}{2}d(PM^2) = PMdPM$, we deduce that (...)

My problem is that I don't understand that last line.

I understand that $\frac{1}{2}d(\vec{PM}\cdot \vec{PM}) = \frac{1}{2}d(PM^2) = PMdPM$

but I don't understand how $\vec{PM}\cdot d\vec{PM} = \frac{1}{2}d(\vec{PM}\cdot \vec{PM})$

Also, I thought that $\vec{PM}\cdot d\vec{PM}  = PMdPM$ can only be true if the angle between the two vectors is zero...

Answer (score 4):

> but I dont understand how

$$\frac{1}{2}d(\vec v \cdot \vec v) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\vec v \cdot d\vec v + d\vec v \cdot v \right) = \vec v \cdot d\vec v$$

> Also, I thought that $\vec{PM}\cdot d\vec{PM}  = PMdPM$ if the angle between the two vectors is zero...

While it's true that $\vec u \cdot \vec v = uv\cos\alpha$, it's also true that

$$dv = \frac{\vec v \cdot d\vec v}{v}$$

You can verify this by, e.g., finding the differential of $\sqrt{v^2_x + v^2_y + v^2_z}$

Thus

$$v\, dv = v \frac{\vec v \cdot d\vec v}{v} = \vec v \cdot d\vec v$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbf v$ be any vector, and let $v$ denote its magnitude (i.e. $v^2=\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf v$). Then
$$\mathbf v\cdot\text d\mathbf v=\frac12\text d(\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf v) = \frac12\text dv^2 = v\ \text dv.$$

Answer (score 1):

> I dont understand how $\vec{PM}\cdot d\vec{PM} = \frac{1}{2}d(\vec{PM}\cdot \vec{PM})$

Read it from right to left and it's a special case of the product rule which holds for arbitrary bilinear functions including the scalar product, ie
$$
d(\vec a\cdot\vec b) = \vec a\cdot d\vec b + d\vec a\cdot\vec b
$$

The easiest way to see this is probably
$$
(\vec a + t\vec v)\cdot(\vec b + t\vec w) = \vec a\cdot\vec b + t\vec a\cdot \vec w + t\vec v\cdot\vec b + t^2\vec v\cdot\vec w
$$
Only the terms linear in $t$ survive once you take the limit $t\to 0$ of the difference quotient.

> Also, I thought that $\vec{PM}\cdot d\vec{PM}  = PMdPM$ can only be true if the angle between the two vectors is zero...

Your intuition is wrong because in general,
$$dPM = d||\overrightarrow{PM}|| \not= ||d\overrightarrow{PM}||$$